# C - String being changed by function unintentionally

Tags: c, string, pointers, methods

I've been using some C lately and I'm relatively new right now. My main problem is that a string I pass to a function is getting changed to a new set of random characters unintentionally. It's difficult for me to explain my problem because I have a bunch of code and I can't share it all. But here are the areas where the problem is:

This code in the main function:

```
char* name = "@";
Var v = NewVar(name, 0);
printf("%s\n", name);
```

Prints:

```
Creating New Value w/ Name: @ 
@
```

-- which is what it should print. However, this code (in another function):

```
printf("Before: %s\n", split[counter]);
Var v = NewVar(split[counter], 0);
printf("After: %s\n", split[counter]);
```

Prints:

```
Before: hi
Creating New Value w/ Name: �
After:�P�
```

"split" (from the code above) is just a 2d array defined as such:

```
char** split = str_split(path, '/')
```

The "NewVar()" function is the following:

```
Var NewVar(char *name, int value){
    printf("Creating New Value w/ Name: %s\n", name);
    Var v;
    v.value = value;
    v.name = name;
    v.varsLen = 0;
    v.vars = (Var*)malloc(sizeof(struct Vars));
    return v;
}
```

I've noticed this problem many times before, but up until now I've had work-arounds. Any advice or explanation as to why this is would be super helpful.

Edit:
This is a full working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** strSplit(char* base, const char* delim){
    char* result[0];
    char *token;
    char str[strlen(base)];
    strcpy(str, base);
    token = strtok(str, delim); 
    int counter = 0;
    while( token != NULL ) {
        result[counter] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        counter++;
    }
    char** split = malloc(counter * sizeof(char*));
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        split[i] = malloc(sizeof(result[i])+1);
        result[i][strlen(result[i])] = '\0';
        split[i] = result[i];
    }
    split[counter] = 0;
    return split;
}

typedef struct Vars{
    char* name;
    struct Vars* vars;
    int value;
    int varsLen;
} Var;

Var NewVar(char *name, int value){
    printf("Creating New Value w/ Name: %s\n", name);
    Var v;
    v.value = value;
    v.name = name;
    v.varsLen = 0;
    v.vars = (Var*)malloc(sizeof(struct Vars));
    return v;
}

void test(char** split){
    char* name = split[0];
    Var v = NewVar(name,0);
    printf("After: %s\n", name);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* name = "@";
    Var v = NewVar(name, 0);
    printf("%s\n", name);
    char** split = strSplit("@/dir1/dir2", "/");
    printf("Before: %s\n", split[0]);
    test(split);
    return 0;
}
```

That prints:

```
Creating New Value w/ Name: @
@
Before: @
Creating New Value w/ Name: @
After:
```

Comment: C does not support _methods_. If you mean _function_, please correct.

Comment: You may not be able to post all code, but you need to post an example we can reason about. For example, can you post the definition of `str_split()`?

Comment: @tgm1024: The standard does not require `auto` variables to be placed on a stack. Neither are `static` local variables placed there if a stack is used.

Comment: @tgm1024: You would not have asked if you knew the difference.

Comment: " It's not like in garbage-collection languages such as Java where you can create an object and have it live fully allocated in memory away from the stack" This is wrong! You can very well do that, similar as Java does in the background. Please read about `malloc`

Comment: Ok, so when my function returns I lose my variable. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This is all loose parts right now.

Comment: @tgm1024: You can very well do OOP in C! Have a look at the Linux kernel for example. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)

Comment: If `Var` is a `struct` that is perfectly fine. The problem is more likely that you're copying the `name` *pointer* to your new `Var`. If another function changes the `name` member of `Var` it will cause the original string to be modified. Please include the definition of `Var` in your question.

Comment: `char* result[0];`? Bzzzzt. Wrong.

Comment: @tgm1024: Yes and call a variable "constant", a pointer "reference", etc. Just take it easy-peasy. The compiler will already inform us about errors. Just be relaxed. In Programming you command an idiot: the computer, so you **have** to be precise about what you say. Even more in languages like C wich are full of tar-pits aka _undefined behaviour_!

Comment: ok I added a full example of some code.

Comment: Also note that the string-literal that you (indirectly) pass to `NewVar` should not be modified at all. Either change the parameter of `NewVar` so that `name` is a `const char *` or assign the literal to an array (`char name[] = "@";`) and pass that instead. Though keep in mind that this array is only 2 elements long and has little potential for meaningful modification.

Comment: Note: `char **` is **not** a 2D array, but an array of pointer to char. A 2D array would be `char [R][C]` for example.

Comment: Ok so now I've noticed that as soon as I reference the variable in a printf it gets changed. Inserting a print right before creating a NewVar in "test()" causes the string to get messed up even before calling NewVar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dissect `str_split()`, shall we?

```
char** strSplit(char* base, const char* delim){
    char* result[0];
```

Our first error. You can't have zero-length arrays. Also, you use the array later, so even if you *could* have zero-length arrays, you couldn't index into them.

```
    char *token;
    char str[strlen(base)];
    strcpy(str, base);
```

Next error. `str` is too small to hold `base`, since `strlen()` doesn't count the null-terminator.

```
    token = strtok(str, delim); 
    int counter = 0;
    while( token != NULL ) {
        result[counter] = token;
```

Misuse of `result`.

```
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        counter++;
    }
    char** split = malloc(counter * sizeof(char*));
```

Remember this, `split` has enough space for `counter` `char *`s...

```
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        split[i] = malloc(sizeof(result[i])+1);
```

Mixed up `strlen()` and `sizeof()`.

```
        result[i][strlen(result[i])] = '\0';
```

Useless. If `somestring[strlen(somestring)]` wasn't already `'\0'`, it wouldn't be `strlen(somestring)`.

```
        split[i] = result[i];
```

This leaks the memory allocated for `split[i]` and keeps a pointer to `str`, which goes out of scope when the function returns. Replace with `strcpy()`.

```
    }
    split[counter] = 0;
```

Did you remember how much space `split` had?

```
    return split;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't know what's going to happen to the passed-in value of `name`.  If it was allocated on the stack, it will be overwritten.  Use a strcpy when assigning to `v.name` and you'll be safe.